# Question with working answer closed. I want to award a bounty

Tags: support, bounty, closed-questions

This question ([Parsing a boolean expression into a MySQL query in PHP - part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578901)) was closed.

I don't want to dispute the closing. However, before it was closed, someone posted an answer which I have tested and found to be working, and which I am unlikely to have been able to code myself, at least without an SQL course.

I would like to award a bounty - (how) can I do so?

Comment: Please, there are not "part 1" and "part 2" questions. Each question need to be independent and self-contained.

Comment: Also, please avoid adding "update" and/or "edit" headers to the questions. Questions should be read naturally, when you add details edit them in so they integrate organically with the rest of the question.

Comment: You want to award a bounty, but you have not accepted the answer, and it has been downvoted three times. Do you think that it is a good and complete answer? Seems strange...

Comment: For what it's worth, the question is not closed at the moment, so you can currently add the bounty.

Comment: I have tested the code and it does what the question asks, so, yes, I would like to award a bounty :-)

Comment: As it stands this answer is vulnerable to SQL injection. In your previous question, you have received a much better answer. I don't think the new answer deserves a bounty. It is a downgrade from what you were given before.

Comment: The question should have been closed. Hard to understand the reopening.

Comment: Irrespective of that, could we please address ***this*** question? If a question is closed, but the questioner wishes to award a bounty, (how) can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way for a bounty to be added to a closed question is for it first to be reopened.

This has already happened for the linked question.

I'm guessing the developers considered this case outside the main workflow, as most bounties are used to attract new answers, and this is not possible for closed questions.
Also it is a bit of a contradiction for the question to be close-worthy, but at the same time to be well answered. The purpose of closing is for preventing answers when they are deemed a-priory useless, since the question is unclear, too-broad, etc.